# I have traffic captured from Wireshark and need copy only their Hex + ASCII dump

Tags: http, wireshark, tshark

I have traffic captured from Wireshark where http requests are tagged. There are about 12 thousand of them and I need to copy only their Hex + ASCII dump. How to do this automatically?
[My capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4kyr.png)

I try tshark, but have only tcp stream (another question, i choise only http)